# Is convergence itself necessary for Riemann´s rearrangement theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have been studying series recently and I´ve gone through the proof of Riemann´s rearrangement theorem among other things. I was given the following related but different statement to prove as an exercise:

A divergent series $\sum{a_k}$ has a convergent rearrangement if and only if the sum of the positive and negative terms diverge to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively and $\lim_{k\to \infty}{a_k}=0$

While trying to prove that the condition was sufficient I wondered: "Can I not just appeal to Riemann´s rearrangement theorem?" However it states that any conditionally convergent series can be rearranaged to converge to any real number or diverge. The statement I´m trying to prove assumes $\sum{a_k}$ diverges. From what I can tell however, in the proof of Riemann´s rearrangement theorem, the convergence itself of the series doesnt seem to be used to prove the theorem, but rather the fact that the sum of the positive and negative terms diverge to $+\infty/-\infty$ and that $\lim_{k\to \infty}{a_k}=0$.

So my question is: Is the convergence itself necessary to prove Riemann´s theorem?

Comment: You are correct. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. Actually, a generalization of Riemann's rearrangement theorem is this: If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is a series of real numbers such that the sum of the positive $a_k$'s is $\infty$, the sum of the negative $a_k$'s is $-\infty$ and that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=0$, then, given $m,M\in\Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ with $m\leqslant M$, there is a rearrangement $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{b(k)}$ of the series such that$$\limsup_{n\in\Bbb N}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=M\quad\text{and}\quad\liminf_{n\in\Bbb N}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=m.$$In particular, when $m<M$, the new series is divergent.